# In a scikit-learn decision tree, how can you identify the decisions that lead to misclassification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to create a decision tree for a dataset and study the resulting confusion matrix. While the confusion matrix tells me how many misclassifications have occurred It does not exactly tell me which particular instances in `X_train` have been misclassified. I am trying to find out which are these misclassified instances and in which leaf node did they end up in. I know I can use `decision_path()` but it doesn't tell me if that particular instance was misclassified or not. My main goal here is to identify where the confused and incorrectly classified instances are ending up. following is my code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()

Y_train=iris.target
X_train=iris.data

clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier( max_depth=3, criterion='entropy')
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
pred=clf.predict(X_train)
print('Accuracy on test data is %.2f' % (accuracy_score(Y_train, pred)))
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]; you can always use [dummy data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) for that purpose.

Comment: That said, the problem sounds ill-defined; in principle, we would need to first *define* a relation between a misclassified example and a specific tree node. Cannot see any unambiguous way to do such a thing.

Comment: @desertnaut is there any way to get all the misclassified instances from the `df` dataframe

Comment: Yes, that's trivial; if this is what you are after, please edit & update the question accordingly to clarify explicitly.

Comment: @desertnaut I am still looking to get bit more information regarding the misclassifications. Can I add it to the existing question? Also I am looking to identify the leaf nodes where the misclassified instances are present

Comment: Please use something **reproducible** e.g the [iris data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html), post what you have tried, and a clear & specific question on what more you want to achieve. Avoid asking more than one questions in the same post (except if they are *really* closely related).

Comment: @desertnaut edited. Do let me know if you require anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got all predictions in `pred` and all training values in `Y_train`

Your misclassified predictions are then simply `pred[pred!=Y_train]`

If you want the features `X_train[pred!=Y_train]`

Comment: @Luie Blanche is there any way to find the decision path of a specific instance from X_train. This way I can find out which instance was misclassified and in which leaf node it ended up

Comment: Well this is where you would use [decision_path](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.decision_path) on `X_train[pred!=Y_train]`

Comment: @Luis Blanche, in case I want to get those misclassified instances where the predicted class is let's say 'Versicolor' then how would I do it? `X_train[pred!=Y_train & pred == 'Versicolor']` ?